# Removing first defined function in bashrc

Tags: ubuntu-12.04

I have a file containing:

```
...
function myfunction(){
                            content
    }
...
function myfunction(){
                            content2
    }
...
```

How can I  automatically remove the first occurrence of myfunction for every such duplica function?

Comment: You can use any IDE to detect duplication or you can create a duplication match regex expression http://www.regular-expressions.info/duplicatelines.html

Comment: Why do you want to remove this? By default bash will the take second(latest) function definition.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove local .bashrc functions with [sed](https://ss64.com/bash/sed.html).

For example, to remove *func1()* and *func2()*, and keep a backup of .bashrc:

```
sed -i.bak -e '/^func1 (/,/}$/d' -e '/^func2 (/,/}$/d' ~/.bashrc
```

Note that it will remove simple functions that includes one block of { ... }. If you have inner { ... } blocks, extend the regexp accordingly.